# 12 violinists, 6 cellists and 2 double bassists

Tags: probability

In a strings selection of an orchestra, there are 12 violinists, 6 cellists and 2 double bassists. 7 members are selected from the section to represent the orchestra at a press conference.

4 violinists, 2 cellists and 1 double bassist are selected. During the press conference, the 7 members are randomly arranged in a line for a photograph. Find the probability that all members who play the same instrument stand next to each other.

My answers:

$1- \frac{7!}{\binom{12}{4}\times\binom{6}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}} = \frac{109}{165}$

I subtracted the probability of arranging the member playing the same equipment separately.

The correct answer is 0.0571. May I know how I can get the answer?

Comment: Your answer seems awfully high.  Just stick with the cellists.  How many arrangements are there with the two cellists next to each other (forget the other requirements).

Comment: Note, the entire first paragraph is irrelevant.  It doesn't matter what the original pool looked like, it only matters how you are arranging the $7$ people in line.

Comment: The poor violists...

Answer (score 1):

As already remarked in the comments, the 1st paragraph is irrelevant, as the 7 people are already selected. You want to calculate number of arrangements where all players playing same instrument are together. The idea is to form 3 groups, 1 for each instrument. You can arrange these 3 groups in factorial 3 ways. But you can also permute people in each group as well. So use the multiplication principle to arrive at the result now.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to focus on the second paragraph the initial choice is already made, let us index this musicians: the $4$ violinists are indexed by $1,2,3,4$, the two cellist $5,6$ and the bassist $7$.
Each positioning is associated with a permutation of $\mathfrak{S}_7$, so there are $7!$ possible positionings. Let us now describe valid permutations $\sigma$:

- They must verify $\sigma(\{1,\dots,4\}) = \{i,\dots,i+3\} = A_1$, $\sigma(\{5,6\}) = \{j,j+1\} = A_2$, $\sigma(\{7\}) = \{k\} = A_3$.
- Plus you have $A_\alpha < A_\beta < A_\gamma$ with $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\} = \{1,2,3\}$. So each positioning of the $A_i$ corresponds to a permutation in $\mathfrak{S}_3$.

So to get a valid permutation, you need to first choose the positioning of the $A_i$, then for each $A_i$ choose in which order you position each number (so it is equivalent to choose a permutation in $\mathfrak{S}_{\sharp A_i}$. Let us denote $V$ the set of valid permutation, we have:
$$V \simeq \mathfrak{S}_3 \times \mathfrak{S}_4 \times \mathfrak{S}_2 \times \mathfrak{S}_1$$
hence
$$\sharp V = 3! \cdot 4! \cdot 2! \cdot 1! = 2!3!4!.$$
The probability to have such a permutation is thus
$$P = \frac{\sharp V}{\sharp \mathfrak{S}_7} = 2 \cdot \frac{3!4!}{7!} = \frac{2}{\binom{7}{3}} = \frac{2}{35} = 0,05714285714$$